# Comparing 2 numbers in a loop not working correctly

Tags: java

In school, we are learning some basic java coding and we are now learning loops and comparing. So what I am trying to do is ask multiple numbers and when typing 2 of the same numbers after each other it needs to print out "woo". The program needs to keep asking for numbers until 2 of the same numbers are entered.

Now my problem is when I enter 2 of the same numbers it works correctly, but when I first type 1 number and then 2 of the same numbers nothing happens.

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2;) {
        int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int number2 = scanner.nextInt();

        if (number1 == number2 || number2 == number1){
            System.out.println("Woo!");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `number1 == number2 || number1 == number2` - what are you trying to do?

Comment: woops, the second one should be number2 == number1

Comment: ..which is exactly the same.. `1 == 1` is the same as... `1 == 1`

Comment: @mrfatmanjunior: You don't need to perform the same comparison twice.  If something is true once, it will be true again.

Comment: is it an infinite loop??

Comment: if i enter 1,2,2 the code doesn't print "woo" thats why im tring to do

Comment: @mrfatmanjunior: If you enter 1, 2, 2 then the application is still waiting for the fourth number.  1 and 2 were the first pair.  They were not equal, so the loop restarted.  Now you enter 2 again.  But you haven't entered the second number for the second pair.

Comment: @david anyway to skip waiting for the 4th number? so if the 2nd and 3rd number are the same it prints "woo!"?

Comment: @David its infinite loop mate he is not increasing i

Comment: @David is right. You should ask only one number per loop, and remember the last typed.

Comment: @Bolzano: It's only infinite if the `if` condition is never satisfied.

Comment: @David yea if condition is i < 2 and look at for decleration he is not not increasing i , i is always 1

Comment: @mrfatmanjunior: Only enter one value per iteration of the loop.  Store the "previously entered" value in a variable and compare the current with the previous.

Comment: @Bolzano: Take a look at the documentation for the `break` statement.  It exits loops.

Comment: @David he says code never reaches the woo so never reaches the break , maybe need to try it

Comment: @Bolzano: The code never reaches that because `nextInt()` is waiting for input.  If he enters another 2, it will be reached and the loop will terminate.  Feel free to test it.

Comment: @David yea inputs are lame 1,2,2 wouldn't work, so this code is actually working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an example of a better code:

```
int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
int number2 = 0;
while (true) {
        number2 = scanner.nextInt();       

        if (number1 == number2){
            System.out.println("Woo!");
            break;
        }
       number1 = number2;

}
```

**Explanation:**
This code will always compare the two last entered numbers. (e.g. `1,2,2` will print `Woo!`).
For better legibility I changed your for loop into a while loop.
`number1 == number2` returns always the same as `number2 == number1`. That's why `number1 == number2 || number2 == number1` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is reading two numbers from STDIN and comparing those in a loop. You always *lose* the previous two numbers in the next iteration.

What you want to do is read one number at a time and compare it to the previously read number.

By the way: if `number1 == number2` is `true` (or `false`), `number2 == number1` is always `true` (or `false`) as well. So the second part of your expression is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is somewhat correct but it will do an extra comparison when it compares the number1 to number2=0.
To avoid that you can do the following:

```
int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
int number2 = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i < 2;) {

if (number1 == number2){
        System.out.println("Woo!");
        break;
    }

        number1 = number2;
        number2 = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

This code will compare every entered number to the previous number to provide the result.